# UITableViewCell layout constraints not behaving as expected

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uitableview

So I have a UITableView with two custom cell classes, both of which have the same width (375), and different heights. The UI looks like Instagram, with a name button and a profile picture, which are the same size in both cells, and positioned identically relatively to each other and the borders. Both cells content view have the same constraints relatively to the profile pic, and both profile pics have the same constraint with the name button. However, at runtime, I get this:

[image]

There is this gap and I cannot pinpoint the reason for it. Both cells' profile pics have aspect fill mode, and both buttons have the same font family and size. There is no constraint on the left of the button in either cell.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check to see if the right constraint of the profile button + image ever changes (in code).

Comment: what's the width of the UITableView? or the background color of the UITableview?

Comment: The UITableView's width is defined as the width of the view it is in, which itself is the width of the screen, like this:

self.view2 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height))
self.tableView2 = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 31, self.view2.frame.width, self.view2.frame.height - 31)).

I am simulating on iPhone 6, which has a screen width larger than 375 (414, apparently), so I did think it might be the reason, but wouldn't both cells resize?

@TroyT : you mean in the console at runtime? I don't change it in the code itself.

Comment: Now I am thinking that it might indeed have to do with the fact that the original size of the cells specified in their xib is smaller than the screen in this case. Since their height is different and they have to maintain their aspect, it makes sense that some dimensions would change in the end.

How can I avoid it? Lose the xib and build the cell programmatically, which would enable me to pass a variable size? Is it even possible?

Comment: No, I don't mean the console at runtime (I did mean change in code, but you said you don't). Can you post the constraints from the storyboard?